# クローズ文にある「編集」を質問文の編集リンクにすることはできますか？

Tags: 機能の要求, 延期, 質問のクローズ

現在のクローズ理由の中で、サイト個別のクローズ理由である「英語なためオフトピック」の説明は以下のようになっています。

> 当サイト ([ja.stackoverflow.com](http://ja.stackoverflow.com)) は Stack Overflow ([stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)) とは独立して日本語の質問を扱うサイトとして運営されています。詳しくは、 [Can I ask questions in English? / 英語で質問してもいいですか？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/3054) をご覧ください。この質問を日本語に編集していただければ、引き続きこのサイトで扱うことができます。英語で質問をするには、[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) へ新しく質問を投稿する必要があります。

ところで最近、コメント欄で `[edit]` と打つと magic link として機能して、`https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/<質問ID>/edit` にリンクする「編集」という文字列に変換されることを知りました。

これと似た仕組みをクローズ理由の説明にも使えないでしょうか？　つまり、「日本語に編集していただければ」の「編集」を /edit にリンクするようにできないでしょうか？

※相対リンクが使えれば良いのですが、質問文では使えないので、おそらくできない……と思っています（簡単には試せないので試していません）。少なくとも質問文では URL の validation がかかっているようで、たとえば `[編集](./edit)` はリンクになりません。

Comment: チーム内のbacklogに追加されたと連絡がありました。Evaluationの時期は未定とのことです m_ _m。

Answer (score 3):

貴重なご意見をどうもありがとうございます。今年の後半になりますが、質問クローズにおけるエクスペリエンスを再検討する予定であり、こちらを考慮に入れさせていただきます。タグを[延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f) に更新しました。